# how to continuously display a file of its last several lines of contents

Tags: linux, unix, split, screen, tail

I am trying to find a Unix command (combination, maybe) on how to continuously display a file of its last several lines of contents. But during this displaying, I want some of the top lines are always displayed on the screen top when the rolling contents reach the screen top.

Is that possible?

1. Suppose I have file, "job.sta", the first 2 lines are:

   ```
   job name, John's job on 2013-Jan-30,...
   Tab1, Tab2, Tab3
   0, 1, 2,
   1, 90, 89
   2, 89, 23
   ...
   ```
2. This file is on its running, its contents are growing, and I don't know what line it's going to end.
3. So I want to display (always) the first 2 lines when using tail command, when the updating contents reaches a Unix shell screen top. I am using PuTTY at the moment.

Reference:
http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/172000-head-tail-how-display-middle-lines.html

Comment: I don't think this could be done by simple shell commands. correct me if I am wrong.  You are asking split the screen into two parts, above part shows the fixed 2 lines (newly first added 2 lines in that session), and down part shows sth like tail -f...  it would look a bit like top command.. not in place changing but scrolling.

Comment: Related: [Unix & Linux: How do I "cat and follow" a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139866/how-do-i-cat-and-follow-a-file)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This will update every 2 seconds rather than whenever data is written to the file, but perhaps that's adequate:

```
watch 'head -n 2 job.sta; tail job.sta'
```

Comment: I tried and tested this is the best answer to suit my purpose. Many thanks.

Also thanks to all the other responses. I also much appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, Bro,
I've got a new question based on your best answer. How can I write a customized command, like watch2. It runs as follows:
$>watch2 job.sta

So, it will get the filename from the command line arguments. 

I've tried much. But I am so pissed by the quote symbols. Do you have any light to shed?

Comment: `watch2() { head -n 2 "$1"; tail "$1"; }`

Comment: I just love SE!

Answer (score 75):

I use this function all the time to monitor a log file in another terminal window.

```
tail -f <filename>
```

I recommend taking it a step forward to look for particular text in the log. Great if you are only interested in seeing some particular entry being written to the file.

```
tail -f <filename> | grep <keyword or pattern>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `screen` to simulate the expected behaviour:

1. Run `screen`, press <kbd>Space</kbd>.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>S</kbd> to split the screen.
3. Resize the top window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> followed by `:resize 4`.
4. In the prompt in the top window, enter `head -n2 file`.
5. Move to the bottom window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
6. Start a new screen session by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>c</kbd>.
7. In the  new prompt, enter `tail -f file`.

Comment: This method seems to be also a solution although there are quite several steps. I also like it! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I use this script to achieve the effect you describe

```
!#/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]; do ls -lt data | head -n 30; sleep 3; echo -en "$(tput cuu 30; tput ed)"; done
```

This runs a command in a loop, and deletes the last lines of the output from the screen before each iteration.

In your case it would look something like

```
!#/bin/bash

while [ 1 ] ;# loop forever
do 
    head -n 2 job.sta ;# display first 2 lines 
    tail -n 30 job.sta ;# display last 30 lines from file
    sleep 3 ;# wait a bit
    echo -en "$(tput cuu 32; tput ed)" ;# delete last 32 lines from screen
done
```

Of course it is a bit ugly before your file reaches 30 lines

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You want the `multitail` program, which not only does the split screen stuff but will also do color-coding.

http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/

Answer (score 1):

You try the following combination
tail -f filename | head -2

Comment: no it is not what OP wants  " I want some of the top lines are always displayed on the screen top when the rolling contents reach the screen top."