# How to activate/run Unix commands in quote symbols?

Tags: unix, command, arguments, symbols, quote

Hi, from the below question:
[how to continuously display a file of its last several lines of contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604397/how-to-continuously-display-a-file-of-its-last-several-lines-of-contents/14610848#14610848)

I've got a new question based on the best answer, by William Pursell. How can I write a customized command, like watch2. It runs as follows:

$>watch2 job.sta

So, it will get the filename from the command line arguments. I don’t have type the command head and tail.

I've tried much. But I am so pissed by the quote symbols. The symbols just deactivate the commands. Do you guys have any light to shed?

Many thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

In file watch2

```
watch "head -n 2 $1; tail $1"
```

you can then run it like

```
./watch2 job.sta
```

Comment: if this is what you want you probably should accept the answer :-P